# Сгенерировать пути зависимостей и кол-во из словаря в файл csv Python

Tags: python, csv, словари, зависимости

Есть словарь следующего вида.

```
d = {
    'root': Counter({'error_log': 1, 'info_log': 1, 'log': 1, 'log_message': 1, 'proc1': 1, 'proc2': 1}), 
    'error_log': Counter({'log': 1}), 
    'info_log': Counter({'log': 1}), 
    'log': Counter({'log_message': 1}), 
    'log_message': Counter(), 
    'proc1': Counter({'error_log': 1}), 
    'proc2': Counter({'info_log': 2})
}
```

Как сформировать пути зависимостей и количество в файл csv, как в примере:

```
path,count
root,1
root/proc1,1
root/proc1/error_log,1
root/proc1/error_log/log,1
root/proc1/error_log/log/log_message,1
root/proc2,1
root/proc2/info_log,2
root/proc2/info_log/log,1
root/proc2/info_log/log/log_message,1
root/error_log,1
root/error_log/log,1
root/error_log/log/log_message,1
root/info_log,1
root/info_log/log,1
root/info_log/log/log_message,1
root/log,1
root/log/log_message,1
root/log_message,1
```